# Install apk files at backend through sms?

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

Is there any way to send .apk file through sms and when the other person will read sms the .apk file gets automatically installed at backend.

Comment: Hmmm...let's see...An SMS is limited to 160 characters (7-bit). Typical APK is 5MB to 20MB (8-bit bytes). That means you would need to send approximately 100 thousand SMS messages to the phone...

Answer (score 1):

In short, no.

You could instead send a link to an apk file that is hosted on a server.  Installing an app on Android always requires user interaction though.

The user would have to click the link, and download the apk.  Then they would have to click on the downloaded file, and Android will offer to install it for them.

That does require that the receiving user has enabled the option to install apps from untrusted locations.  Android will prompt the user to turn that option on if they try to install an apk though.